# Schwarz Pick Theorem (Maximum Modulus approach)

Tags: complex-analysis

**(Schwarz Pick Theorem) Let $f(z)$ be a non-constant analytic function on the region
$$D= \{z \in \mathbb{C}~|~|z| \leq 1\}$$
Suppose $$|f(z)| \leq 1$$ 
for all $z \in D$. Show that if $|w| <1$, then $$\dfrac{|f^{'}(w)|}{1-|f(w)|^{2}} \leq \dfrac{1}{1-|w|^{2}}$$**

> Can anyone verify if my proof is correct.

Consider the function $$g(z) = \dfrac{f(z)-f(w)}{1-\overline{f((w)}f(z)}$$

Now, since $|f(z)| \leq 1$ on $|z| = 1$ and $f$ is non constant, by maximum modulus principle, $|f(z)| \neq 1$ in the region $|z| < 1$.

Let us have for any fixed $w$ such that $|w| <1$, we must have $|f(z)| < 1$.

Hence, let $|z| \leq 1$ and fixed $|w| < 1$, we have $|f(z)| \leq 1$ and $|f(w)| < 1$. Hence $$|g(z)| \leq 1~~~\text{ for all } |z| \leq 1$$

Note that for any $|z| = 1$ and fixed $|w| <1$, we will have $$\left|\dfrac{z-w}{1-z\overline{w}}\right|=1$$

Consider only the points on $|z| = 1$ and any fixed $|w| <1$ ,we will still have $$|g(z)| \leq 1 \text{ and } \left|\dfrac{z-w}{1-z\overline{w}}\right|=1$$

Observe on $|z| = 1$, let $$|G(z)| = \dfrac{|g(z)|}{\left|\dfrac{z-w}{1-z\overline{w}}\right|} = \dfrac{|g(z)|}{1} \leq \dfrac{1}{1}=1$$

By maximum modulus, $$|G(z)| \leq 1$$
for all $|z| \leq 1$

Note that before applying max modulus, $G(z) = \dfrac{g(z)}{\dfrac{z-w}{1-z\overline{w}}}$  need to be analytic throughout $B(0,1)$ and continuous on its boundary. Well we simplify $G(z)$ to become $$G(z) = \dfrac{(f(z)-f(w))(1-z\overline{w})}{(1-\overline{f(w)}f(z))(z-w)}$$

With some simple verification, we first deduce that $1-\overline{f(w)}f(z) \neq 0$ for all $|w| < 1, |z| \leq 1$. So we are left with only the singularity $z = w$ which is contained inside $B(0,1)$. However, $w$ is a removable singularity, and hence $G(z)$ is analytic throughout $\overline{B(0,1)}$

Hence $$\left|\dfrac{f(z)-f(w)}{1-\overline{f(w)}f(z)}\right| \leq \left|\dfrac{z-w}{1-z\overline{w}}\right| \Rightarrow \left|\dfrac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w}\right| \leq \left|\dfrac{1-f(z)\overline{f(w)}}{1-z\overline{w}}\right|$$

Let us take the limit of both sides as $z \to w$, we thus have the desired inequality:

$$|f^{'}(w)| \leq \dfrac{1-|f(w)|^{2}}{1-|w|^{2}}  \Rightarrow \dfrac{|f^{'}(w)}{1-|f(w)|^{2}} \leq \dfrac{1}{1-|w|^{2}}$$